# Get scrollview on top event

Tags: android, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have this code on my gridview on touch event.

```
        gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }

            // Handle ListView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Inside `MotionEvent.Action_UP` case, I want something like this.

```
if(v.getParent().ScrollisOnTop){
    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    }
else{
    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
```

Mean when parent scroll is already on top, disallow scrollView to intercept

Else allow scrollView to intercept.

Comment: You receive the scroll position in `onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY)` - perhaps store the y coordinate as a field variable after this method and compare within onTouch()?

Comment: I think you have the answer I want, Can to express more ?

Comment: I cant find this method anyWhere.